# Add styles in Webpack css-loader without localIdentName on specific classes

Tags: webpack, css-loader

I'm using webpack url-loader to load css files and access them via CSS modules. These styles are transformed like this `shared-assets-_nav---nav---JLuu1 ul > li > a`.

How do I change styles for unhashed styles which are added by libraries? I.e. React Router's  adds active classname.

How would I add css on this class?

Answer (score 0):

Just add :global { } to your styling. That way, in css-loader, the style name isn't changed.

Example:

```
:global {
  ul > li > .active {
    color: var(--focus);
    &::after {
      display: table;
      clear: both;
      content: "";
    }
  }
}
```